# Работа с большими InnoDB таблицами в MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

Ситуация такова: есть порядка 10 таблицы `INNODB` партициированных, с опцией `innodb-file-per-table=1` (каждая таблица/партиция таблицы в отдельном `innodb`-файле - на это были другие причины). Размер таблиц около 40ГБ каждая.

При штатной работе система справляется с нагрузкой. Оговорюсь сразу, что в таблицах статистические данные. Накопленные данные обрабатываются каждые N минут. Однако, если по какой-либо причине, обработки не было более чем на 30 минут (например, обслуживание системы - это редко, но раз в год приходится вносить изменения), то всё - начинают сыпаться ошибки превышения времени ожидания.

Система развивалась постепенно. Изначально таблицы были без партиций, но с увеличением объёма данных, пришлось вносить много корректив: полный пересмотр индексов, парциирование, переделывание запросов. Результат, как говорится, был на лицо.

Но с каждым разом, внесение изменений требует много времени. Сегодня, например, простой `ALTER TABLE` занят 2:45 часа. Это неприемлемо.

Немного отвлёкся. Итак, как я говорил, обработка накопленных данных требует много ресурсов и `SELECT` начинают возвращать ошибки превышения времени ожидания. Конечно, сами эти таблицы в запросах не участвуют, а работа идёт с результатами запросов на них. В итоге, есть эти 10 таблиц, общим размером около 400ГБ и несколько десяток мелких, суммарный размер которых сопоставим (а может и ещё нет) с размером одной большой таблицы. Проблем с мелкими таблицами нет.

Мой вопрос такой: как можно решить проблему с ошибками превышения времени? Сервак, вроде, не плохой - 8 ядер xeon, 64 оперативки. И это только сервер БД. Разумеется, вся система не располагается на одной машине.
Должен заметить, что узким местом здесь является обработка больших таблиц с записью результатов в малые. Как можно решить это? Можнои даже, чтобы `SELECT` выдавал немного неактуальные цифры (то, что успел сохранить), но без этого блокирования.

Есть мысли?

Comment: Что показывает мониторинг? Какой ресурс в atop краснеет, например?

Comment: atop не смотрел. в `top` `load average` доходил до 5, что вообще ничего с учётом 8 ядер. я всё же склоняюсь к версии скорости работы винта.
но эта скорость мне не критична. меня больше интересует как сделать так, чтобы при частом `insert` `select` выдавал результаты, а не блокировался.

Comment: Касаемо долгого `ALTER TABLE` мне советовали использовать **Percona Toolkit**, но оговорка в описании мне не совсем понравилась - говорилось о том, что есть вероятность потери данных. А мне это ну никак не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Начинать решение проблем с производительностью надо с анализа и измерений. Вам помогут такие инструменты, как

- atop система в целом
- htop система
- iotop диск
- iftop сеть
- iops диск

На основании этих измерений можно делать выводы о том, каких ресурсов вам не хватает. А затем думать, можно ли подкрутить базу так, чтобы стало хватать. Или пора бежать в магазин за SSD? Или за оперативкой?

Comment: Физического доступа к серверу не имею. Как я упоминул в предыдущем комменте, дело скорее всего в дисках, потому как сервер в целом почти простаивает. Если быть точнее, успевает всё нормально обработать. На самом сервере больше ничего не крутится, а работы с сетью ограничивается копированием файлов из локальной сети по FTP раз в несколько минут.
Меня беспокоят ошибки с превышениями времени ожадания. При `INSERT` ставится блокировка и `SELECT` не может дождаться ответа. А этих `INSERT` (bulk insert, если быть точным) много.

Comment: insert поверх select прекрасно делает firebird. Не знаю, что нужно в майсюкюэле навертеть, чтобы оно также работало.

Comment: В MySQL есть конструкция `INSERT DELAYED`, но она не работает с `InnoDB` таблицами. Точнее сказать **`INSERT DELAYED` работает только с таблицами типа `ISAM` и `MyISAM`**

Answer (score 0):

Если еще актуально. Использовал Percona Toolkit, потери данных не было. Percona Toolkit создает копию таблицы с нужным столбцом при использовании alter, проставляет индексы и затем заполняет ее данными. В принципе вы можете это делать вручную, используя sql-запросы. Кстати, если делать вручную и вначале заполнить новую таблицу с новым столбцом данными, а затем делать индексы для столбцов, то так будет быстрее. У самого была похожая ситуация, Percona Toolkit справлялась ну очень медленно.

Comment: На сервере MySQL Percona'вский. Хотя, его инструменты я не использовал. Была одна попытка (уже не скажу что именно нужно было сделать), но покопавшись в сети по отзывам, тот инструмент был нестабильным (точнее, была вероятность потери/повреждения данных), что в моём случае недопустимо. Это было давно и после этого я уже не смотрел в сторону Percona Toolkit. Возможно, сейчас дела обстоят лучше.